# XNA and Lidgren Error: Trying to read past buffer size?

Tags: networking, xna, lidgren

I am trying to create an online game using XNA and the Lidgren Networking Library. However, right now I am having trouble sending and receiving any messages without getting the error: **"Trying to read past the buffer size - likely caused by mismatching Write/Reads, different size or order."**

I send the messages to the client like this:

```
if (btnStart.isClicked && p1Ready == "Ready")
{
    btnStart.isClicked = false;
    NetOutgoingMessage om = server.CreateMessage();
    CurrentGameState = GameState.City;
    om.Write((byte)PacketTypes.Start);                                    
    server.SendMessage(om, server.Connections, NetDeliveryMethod.Unreliable, 0);
    numPlayers = 2;
    Console.WriteLine("Game started.");
}
```

Where PacketTypes.Start is part of an enum set up to distinguish between different messages.

The client receives this message like so:

```
    if (joining)
{
    NetIncomingMessage incMsg;
    while ((incMsg = client.ReadMessage()) != null)
    {
    switch (incMsg.MessageType)
    {


    case NetIncomingMessageType.Data:
    if (incMsg.ReadByte() == (byte)PacketTypes.Ready)
    {
        p1Ready = "Ready";                                                
    }
    else if (incMsg.ReadByte() == (byte)PacketTypes.Start)
    {
        CurrentGameState = GameState.City;
        Console.WriteLine("Game started");
        numPlayers = 2;
    }

    break;

    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Server not found, Retrying...");
    break;

        }
    }
}
```

But no matter what I've tried, I still get that error. Please, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only write one byte to your packets when you send them:

```
om.Write((byte)PacketTypes.Start);
```

But read two when you receive them:

```
// One read here
if (incMsg.ReadByte() == (byte)PacketTypes.Ready)
{
    p1Ready = "Ready";                                                
}
// Second read here
else if (incMsg.ReadByte() == (byte)PacketTypes.Start)
```

**Edit**

To resolve the issue change your code to this:

```
case NetIncomingMessageType.Data:
    byte type = incMsg.ReadByte(); // Read one byte only

    if (type == (byte)PacketTypes.Ready)
    {
        p1Ready = "Ready";                                                
    }
    else if (type == (byte)PacketTypes.Start)
    {
        CurrentGameState = GameState.City;
        Console.WriteLine("Game started");
        numPlayers = 2;
    }

break;
```

Comment: Hm, putting this: byte temp = incMsg.ReadByte(); first , then instead of incMsg.ReadByte() == (byte)PacketTypes.Ready, I use temp == (byte)PacketTypes.Ready and it seems to work.

Comment: Yes because now you only make a single call to ReadByte and so only read one byte not two.

Comment: So, should I stick with that method? Or is your method above more effective for the future? Sorry if this is a stupid question I'm new to this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant so I just wrote out how I think the code should look...